# automatic weight.. something wrong

Tags: modeling, modifiers, rigging, weight-painting

[image: model]i try everything in blender tutorial but always the same problem... is there any solution for this situation? when i move the left leg then right leg follow, neck move then the whole body move, move my forearm then this time again all body moves....
what i tried

1. apply modifier
2. export and import
3. delete blender and download again
4. weight painting
   [image: when i move][image: move leg][image]
   [this is the problem](https://youtu.be/igUBPY0xrJM)

[this is the model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14eIm7klMRa2FbsJZNxsEi2JSFJxjWlPc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi. While videos *can* be helpful, we ideally want to answer questions without the need for external links. They may break at some point and then the question is unclear to other people who may have the same problem. Please [add some images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) to explain the issue. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for advice!^^